# How can I retrieve the ID of a collection_select and display a list of items every time the select changes?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@exam) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Year %>
    <%= f.collection_select :year_id, Year.order(:name), :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :marks_secured %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And, every time the select box changes (i.e. a different year is selected), I want to display the list of students for the selected year. The list must be shown within the same page.

I don't know how to grab the ID of the selected item and use it back inside the view/controller in order to achieve this..

Here are my models:

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :year
  has_many  :exams
end
```

exam.rb

```
class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :year
  belongs_to  :student
end
```

year.rb

```
class Year < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :students
  has_many  :exams
end
```

Comment: Should be available on @exam.year_id

Comment: I actually want to output the list of student on the same page as soon as I select the year ( I know some JS has to come up at some point ) then submit the student_id so that it's stored as a single record [ :year_id, :student_id, :exam_id ]@dbugger

Comment: I'll update my answer, but please update the question with the information you just provided, the original question is different from what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ajax in order to show the list of students every time the `select` option is changed; to do so you need to make several changes.

First, you need to determine where in your view you would like to display de students, for example, try adding a `div` in your form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@exam) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Year %>
    <%= f.collection_select :year_id, Year.order(:name), :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  </div>

  <div id="students"><!-- Students will be listed here --></div>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :marks_secured %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Next, add a script (on the same view where your `form` is) to detect when the `select` changes, and update (via ajax) the students list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    function getStudents() {
      var year = $('#exam_year_id').val();

      $.ajax({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: "<%= students_url %>",
        data: { year: year },
        success: function(response) {
          $('#students').html(html);
        }
      });
    }

    $('#exam_year_id').on('change', getStudents );
    getStudents();
  });
</script>
```

In this example the function `getStudents` is called whenever the `select` changes (`$('#exam_year_id').on('change', getStudents );`) and after the page loads (`getStudents();`), so the students from the default year selected (that is, when your page first loads) get listed.

Also notice that we are replacing the content of the `div` recently added with a variable called `html` which will be delivered within a view by your students controller (next step).

Now you need to update your students controller to get the list of students for the selected year:

```
def index
  @Students = Student.where(year: params[:year])
end
```

And create your view with the list of students:

```
var html = "<select name='exam[student_id]' id='exam_student_id'>";

<% @Students.each do |student| %>
  html = html + "<option value='<%= student.id %>'><%= student.name %></option>"
<% end %>

html = html + "</select>";
```

The view must be named `index.js.erb` (instead of a `index.html.erb`) and will contain javascript; in this example it only contains a the variable (`html`) with the list of students (the list is created as another `select` box but you can change it).

Finally, in your exams controller add an `update` action that will update the `exam`'s details:

```
def update
  exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
  exam.student_id = exam_params[:student_id]
  exam.year_id = exam_params[:year_id]
  exam.save!
end

private

def exam_params
  params.require(:exam).permit(:year_id, :student_id)
end
```

And that's it! Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually want to output the list of student on the same page as soon as I select the year ( I know some JS has come up at some point ) then  submit the student_id so that it's stored as a single record [ :year_id, :student_id, :exam_id ]. @Gerry